# Are dalli gem's write operations asynchronous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I want to use memcached for session store which is on a different server it will be accessed by rails app using dalli gem. So are dalli gem's write operations asynchronous? If not is it possible to make them async? As it shouldn't be the bottleneck for memcached to serve efficiently.

By asynchronous I mean rails server won't wait for session operation to get completed.

Comment: Apparently, dalli [_can be async_](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/issues/144), but it has to be used from within an async environment.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you, can you write as answer so I can accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Sergio's comment:
Apparently, dalli [can be async](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/issues/144), but it has to be used from within an async environment.